# how to convert negative hexadecimal to decimal

Tags: c, encoding, numbers, decimal, negative-number

hi I want to know how it is possible to convert a hexadecimal negative value (to complement encoding) to decimal, easily without converting hexadecimal to binary and then multiplying each bit in by a power of 2 and sums all the value to get the result, it takes too much time :
example of number (32 bits) : 0xFFFFFE58

so how can I do it?

Comment: Computer any number usually considered binary.

Comment: I am not sure what representation your decimal is supposed to take. Tried `sprintf(buffer, "%d", 0xFFFFFE58);`?

Comment: How can you do what? read a hex number and print is as decimal? Please clarify your question

Comment: i want to do convert a hexadecimal number to decimal number without using the computer.

Comment: `int d= (int)0xFFFFFE58;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

without using a computer you can calculate it like this:

```
0xFFFF FE58 = - 0x1A8 = -(1 * 16² + 10 * 16 + 8) = -(256 + 160 + 8) = -424
```

`0xFFFF FE58` is a negative number in 2's complement. To get the absolute value you have to invert all bits and add 1 in binary. You also can subtract this number from the first number out of range (0x1 0000 0000)

```
 0x100000000
-0x0FFFFFE58
      =
 0x0000001A8
```

now we know that your number is `-0x1A8`. now you have to add up the digits multiplied with their place value. 8 * 16^0 + A (which is 10) * 16^1 + 1 * 16^2 = 424. So the decimal value of your number is -424.

Answer (score 0):

do a calculation on the positive number, then convert to the negative with Two's complement.

see explanation here for positive conversion from hexa to decimal:

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/numHexToDec/

basically:

1. Get the right most digit of the hex number, call this digit the currentDigit.
2. Make a variable, let's call it power.  Set the value to 0.
3. Multiply the current digit with (16^power), store the result.
4. Increment power by 1.
5. Set the the currentDigit to the previous digit of the hex number.
6. Repeat from step 3 until all digits have been multiplied.
7. Sum the result of step 3 to get the answer number.